# How to split cell values comma delimited

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell in excel which contains below values:

```
abc,efg
```

now both strings are present in single cell separated with comma.

now I want string "efg" to move downwards cell with help of some formula where I can use `,` as a delimiter.

Comment: You cannot 'move' something with a formula; you **can** make a copy of the latter 'piece' and have the formula return that but a formula cannot change the original cell's value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1))
```

*Assuming the string is in cell `A1`*

Comment: Thanks for your timely help but when i used this formula it says value used in this formula is of wrong datatype.

Comment: @ameykambli Have you changed the references to `A1` to reference whichever cell your string is in?